# Qlik excel data import for columns with same name

Tags: qliksense

I have 4 different excel sheets and I have been loading them in QlikSense. The common column names get suffix EXPORT WORKSHEET1 . Although I change the  name of the sheet after importing, the alias remains the same. How can I change that? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet?

Comment: Hi Stefan. There is no code. I am just loading the excel sheets into data manager using drag and drop.

Comment: @Doodle: I saw your answer below, but still if you want to use the same name then I think you can select the folder as source and from EDIT screen you can manage Sheet name. But yes while loading you will have to give different name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the name of the sheet within the excel sheet before importing it into QlikSense. Thanks.